# How to obtain an Earth Crystal in Stardew Valley?

Tags: stardew-valley

I've been playing Stardew Valley on my Xbox One for about a week or so, and I can't seem to get earth crystals. I see them commonly in the mines, but I have no clue as to how to actually get them as an item. I cant seem to use any of my tools on them (the same goes for quartz). I don't desperately need them, but it'd be nice to know how to get them, and if anyone knows how to please let me know.

Answer (score 21):

Just pick them up like you would pick up a ripe vegetable on your farm.

Comment: If you're unable to pick them up, your inventory may be full. You can drop something else to make room, or buy the backpack expansions at Pierre's store.

Answer (score 2):

They are found in the mines in level 1 to 50. you pick them up by clicking A on them or the green button while facing them.